# In liferay, how can I transform an mbdiscussion into a standard MBMessage?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I would like to move a few comments on a page layout to become standard messages in a message board.

How can I do that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there's no magic flag to change on such a message. As you'll have different metadata, you'll have to read the comment (through the API) and create a message-board message in a category that you'll find appropriate. As it's all text content, you'll just contain the message board message with the same content and author. But all of the other metadata (category, threading etc) you'll have to handle for yourself